# How to take two characters as input continuously?

Tags: c, character, scanf

I have to take input as:

```
A B
C D
E A
```

So I wrote the code like this :

```
char ch[50][2];    
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    scanf("%c%c",&ch[i][0],&ch[i][1]);
}
```

But it is taking only two inputs and then, I am getting runtime error. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: try `scanf(" %c %c",&ch[i][0],&ch[i][1]);` to escape the newline `\n`

Comment: I believe you would need a space between the 2 `%c`s. Also, most users would recommend you use `fgets` instead of `scanf` and then just parse the `char*` output

Comment: @Haris Why is there a space _before_ the `%c`?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the runtime error. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QGQrhGrh9IpIRYes

Comment: @Arc676 To skip the newline in the second and subsequent iterations of the loop.

Comment: Please describe "getting runtime error"

Comment: @Haris You may post that as an answer.

Comment: `for(i=0;i<n;i++)` should be `for(i=0;i<3;i++)`

Answer (score 1):

This is the method I often use: read the characters as strings.

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    char buf1[2], buf2[2];
    scanf("%1s%1s",buf1,buf2);
    ch[i][0]=buf1[0];
    ch[i][1]=buf2[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
scanf(" %c %c",&ch[i][0],&ch[i][1]);
```

This would escape the newline `\n` character left in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a space between chars in `scanf`

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    scanf(" %c %c", &ch[i][0], &ch[i][1]);
}
```

This will cause `scanf` to ignore whitespace between characters. An extra space at the beginning is needed to also ignore new line character that the user inserts by pressing enter.